# Android : Dialog occupy 100% width

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.theme_dialog);
 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_name);
 dialog.setCancelable(false);

 dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
 dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Above code occupy around 90% width but I want 100 percent.

Answer (score 12):

Add below style

```
<style name="Theme_Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>
</style>
```

and

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_Dialog);
```

Comment: Not achieving the full width

Comment: I need a full width dialog using DialogFragment.When I applied this solution,its not working

Comment: @AbrahamMathew Its for only Dialog not for DialogFragment

Comment: As mentioned by @mrudul-tora use
`dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

Answer (score 6):

Try following code, this will solve your issue.

```
    //Grab the window of the dialog, and change the width
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
    //This makes the dialog take up the full width
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    window.setAttributes(lp);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to change this

```
 dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

to this

```
 dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Comment: `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` and `WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` both have the same constant value so this will not have any effect

Comment: The second param is height, it doesn't affect the dialog width. And yes, it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,use RelativeLayout as the parent view of custom dialog, then set the width to match_parent and height to wrap_content in the xml file of your custom dialog.
Then use this code in java file...

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(AllProductListActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_custom_dialog_layout);                
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));             
dialog.getWindow().setLayout.(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
dialog.show();
```

As you will read many solutions only used setLayout(), that alone cannot make the width of dialog to match_parent. But here,on adding the below line the width of dialog will be match_parent while the height will be wrap_content.

> ```
> dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
> ```

Comment: This solution worked for me.
The trick is to use `setBackgroundDrawable`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a RelativeLayout as the root view of your dialog.